# Propel: PHP Fatal error: Class 'Criteria' not found

Tags: php, criteria, propel

I'm trying to do a `filterBy` query in Propel with `Criteria::XXXX` as a second argument. Like the example in the documentation:

```
$books = BookQuery::create()
  ->filterByTags(array('novel', 'russian'), Criteria::CONTAINS_ALL)
  ->find();
```

But this always fails giving me the error that the Class Criteria is not found.

Otherwise Propel works just fine. Anybody an idea how this could be fixed?

Comment: Have you included the proper class for Criteria? ('\Propel\Runtime\Query\Criteria',)

Comment: Didn't know that I have to include it ... thought it would work just by including Propel alone
I put this on top of the php file ...
use \Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria;
and now it seems to work 
If you turn your comment into an answer I'll mark it as the right answer or should I just delete it cause it was so noob :)
cheers Florian

Comment: Don't delete it, maybe someone else will look for this too one day

Comment: I installed propel via composer and I still have this issuee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the class `'\Propel\Runtime\Query\Criteria'`

Comment: If the OP installs using Composer, this isn't necessary.

Comment: You're absolutely right. But with this error, OP probably doesn't use composer.

Answer (score 0):

For Propel 2 :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/path_to/autoload.php';
use Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\Criteria;
```